# Adding dynamic mouseover to all entries in a column in a DataTable with Shiny (R)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I was pretty sure that there is an answer already out there to my question,
but no matter how hard I searched I couldn't find any solution that could work in this case. So if this is considered to be trivial, please don't shoot.

Now here's the problem:

Assuming we are rendering a dataTable with Shiny, I would like to grab the id of every cell (rowID+columnID) when I hover over over the cell and present dynamically output from the underlying datasets. 
I know that there are already solutions for mouseovers, such as shinyBS or this example here:

```
    #server.R:
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  dat <- list(iris,cars) 
  output$tabset <- renderUI({
    tabs <- list()
    for(i in c(1,2)){
      id <- paste("id",i, sep="")
      tabs[[i]] <- tabPanel(title=id,DT::dataTableOutput(outputId=id)) #dynamic panels
    }
    do.call(tabsetPanel,c(tabs, id='Panel'))
  })

  lapply(1:2,function(i){
    id <- paste("id",i, sep="")
    output[[id]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
      dat[[i]]},
      extensions = c('Scroller'),
      options=list(deferRender=TRUE, dom='T<"clear">fitrS', scrollY=540, searchHighlight = TRUE,
                   scrollCollapse=TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE,
                   columnDefs = list(list(width = '60%', targets = '_all',
                                          render = JS("function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                                                      "return type === 'display' && data.length > 5 ?",
                                                      "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 5) + '...</span>' : data;",
                                                      "}"
                                          )))),
      callback = JS('table.page(3).draw(false);'),
      escape=FALSE, rownames=TRUE,class = 'table-condensed', server=TRUE)
      })
})
```

And the ui.R

```
    #ui.R:
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('tabset')
)
```

There is a mouseover that trims a cell if its length is 5 or more. What I would like to do now is to see if it the highlighted cell comes from panel with 'id1', is from column Sepal.Length and the mouseover should show data from panel 'id2', that had the same rowId as in Sepal.Length and should show the data from column dist. 
Basically I want don't want to present static content or just modify the string that is already in that cell, but rather dynamically present additional content depending on what cell has been hovered over. 
Is that possible with Shiny and JavaScript?

Thanks for any input.